# Label ggplot Geom_Bar with total categorical value

Tags: r, ggplot2, stackedbarseries

With This CSV:

```
Year,Permanent Wetland Loss,Permit Wetlands CRE,Permit Conservation,ARM Conservation,ARM Restoration,ARM Enhancement,Conservation_Total,EnRes_Total
2008,61,4,1271,,,,1271,4
2009,73,4,2707,1403,,,4110,4
2010,70,26,1440,1030,,,2470,26
2011,52,32,781,2537,,,3318,32
2012,41,8,211,2675,,,2886,8
2013,68,21,265,2191,6.6,80,2456,107.6
2014,48,1,114,1165,,,1279,1
2015,73,0,947,2381,11,,3328,11
2016,33,18,116,3751,,,3867,18
2017,59,15,136,,,,136,15
2018,77,1,89,8177,,,8266,1
```

I am executing this code:

```
library(reshape2) # for melt
input_df <- read.csv("ARM_PERMIT_COMB.csv", header=TRUE)
names(input_df) <- c('Year', 'Wetland Loss','Restoration/Enhancement - Permit','Conservation - Permit',
                   'Conservation - ARM', 'Restoration - ARM', 'Enhancement - ARM', 'Con - Total', 'EnRes - Total') 

input_df <- input_df[,c(1,5,4,3,6,7,2)]
melted <- melt(input_df, "Year")

melted$cat <- ''
melted[melted$variable == 'Wetland Loss',]$cat <- "Loss"
melted[melted$variable == 'Restoration/Enhancement - Permit',]$cat <- "Enhancement / Restoration"
melted[melted$variable == 'Restoration - ARM',]$cat <- "Enhancement / Restoration"
melted[melted$variable == 'Enhancement - ARM',]$cat <- "Enhancement / Restoration"
melted[melted$variable == 'Conservation - ARM',]$cat <- "Conservation"
melted[melted$variable == 'Conservation - Permit',]$cat <- "Conservation"


ggplot(melted, aes(x = cat, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'stack') + facet_grid(~ Year) + 
  labs(title = 'Wetlands Loss, Conservation, Enhancement, Restoration, ', y='Acres', x='', subtitle = 'Years 2008 - 2018') +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.3, hjust=1)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("chartreuse2","green4", "steelblue3", "yellow3","orangered2", "grey33","white","white"), 
                    name="Impacts and\nMitigation") + 
  geom_text(aes(label=value), vjust = -3)
```

To generate this graph:

[image]

Which is perfect in every way except for the fact that I want the labels to reflect the sums of the entire stacked bar and not all the individual parts that make up the stacked bar.

Zoom in:

[image]

Things I have tried:
 - plotting a chart behind this one with white bars that this plots over - wasn't able to figure that out.
 - trying to get the geom_text to reference a different dataframe taht represented the totals (geom_text(aes(label=melted_total$value), vjust = -3)) which didn't work.

EDIT:

This code gets me very very close to what I want, just have to figure out how to hide the two 'Totals' in the legend:

```
library(reshape2) # for melt
input_df <- read.csv("ARM_PERMIT_COMB.csv", header=TRUE)
input_total_df <- input_df[,c(1,2,8,9)]

names(input_df) <- c('Year', 'Wetland Loss','Restoration/Enhancement - Permit','Conservation - Permit',
                   'Conservation - ARM', 'Restoration - ARM', 'Enhancement - ARM', 'Con - Total', 'EnRes - Total')   
names(input_total_df) <- c('Year', 'Wetland Loss','Con - Total', 'EnRes - Total')   


input_df <- input_df[,c(1,5,4,3,6,7,2)]
melted <- melt(input_df, "Year")
melted_total <- melt(input_total_df, "Year")


melted$cat <- ''
melted[melted$variable == 'Wetland Loss',]$cat <- "Loss"
melted[melted$variable == 'Restoration/Enhancement - Permit',]$cat <- "Enhancement / Restoration"
melted[melted$variable == 'Restoration - ARM',]$cat <- "Enhancement / Restoration"
melted[melted$variable == 'Enhancement - ARM',]$cat <- "Enhancement / Restoration"
melted[melted$variable == 'Conservation - ARM',]$cat <- "Conservation"
melted[melted$variable == 'Conservation - Permit',]$cat <- "Conservation"

melted_total$cat <- ''
melted_total[melted_total$variable == 'Wetland Loss',]$cat <- "Loss"
melted_total[melted_total$variable == 'Con - Total',]$cat <- "Conservation"
melted_total[melted_total$variable == 'EnRes - Total',]$cat <- "Enhancement / Restoration"


ggplot(melted, aes(x = cat, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'stack') + facet_grid(~ Year) + 
  labs(title = 'Wetlands Loss, Conservation, Enhancement, Restoration, ', y='Acres', x='', subtitle = 'Years 2008 - 2018') +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.3, hjust=1)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("white","chartreuse2","green4", "steelblue3", "white", "yellow3","orangered2", "grey33", "white"), 
                    name="Impacts and\nMitigation") + 
  geom_text(data=melted_total, aes(label=value), vjust = -1, size=2)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`reshape2` has been replaced by `tidyr`'s `spread()` and `gather()` operations. You can greatly simplify your code by using the `tidyverse`. Also, it is probably bad practice to fill your factors to make them invisible. It is easier to set `inherit.aes = FALSE` and set new `aes()` parameters.

Consider this code:

```
library(tidyverse)

input_df <- read_csv("ARM_PERMIT_COMB.csv") %>%
  magrittr::set_colnames(
    c('Year', 'Wetland Loss','Restoration/Enhancement - Permit',
      'Conservation - Permit', 'Conservation - ARM', 'Restoration - ARM',
      'Enhancement - ARM', 'Con - Total', 'EnRes - Total')
    ) %>% 
  select(-contains("Total")) %>%
  gather(Variable, Value, -Year) %>%
  mutate(Category = case_when(
    Variable == "Wetland Loss" ~ "Loss",
    str_detect(Variable, "Restoration|Enhancement") ~ "Enhancement / Restoration",
    str_detect(Variable, "Con") ~ "Conservation",
    TRUE ~ "Enhancement / Restoration"
  ))

ggplot(input_df, aes(x = Category, y = Value, fill = Variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack") + 
  facet_grid(~Year) +
  labs(title = 'Wetlands Loss, Conservation, Enhancement, Restoration, ', 
       y = 'Acres', x = '', subtitle = 'Years 2008 - 2018') +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.3, hjust = 1)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("chartreuse2","green4", "steelblue3", 
                               "yellow3","orangered2", "grey33"), 
                    name = "Impacts and\nMitigation") + 
  geom_text(data = input_df %>% 
              group_by(Year, Category) %>% 
              summarise(Value = sum(Value, na.rm = TRUE)),
            aes(label = Value, x = Category, y = Value), inherit.aes = FALSE,
            vjust = -1, size = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it - Had to adjust the breaks in the *scale_fill_manual*:

```
 scale_fill_manual(breaks=c('Year', 'Wetland Loss','Restoration/Enhancement - Permit','Conservation - Permit',
                             'Conservation - ARM', 'Restoration - ARM', 'Enhancement - ARM'),
                    values=c("white","chartreuse2","green4", "steelblue3", "white", "yellow3","orangered2", "grey33", "white"), 
                    name="Impacts and\nMitigation") +
```

And that cut out the white legend entries.